# Является ли конкретизированное более общее слово приложением?

Tags: приложение

Для информации, которая не может быть правильно понята и обработана, учёные придумали очень точное слово шум.

Является ли в данном случае "слово шум" приложением и почему не отделяется кавычками или тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Для информации, которая не может быть правильно понята и обработана, учёные придумали очень точное слово шум.*

Да, здесь есть приложение: придумали (что?)слово (какое?) шум. Шум-приложение.

**Если в сочетании двух нарицательных существительных первое обозначает родовое понятие, а второе — видовое** (цветок хризантема, газ кислород, суп харчо, попугай какаду), **то дефис между ними не ставится**.

Но если такое сочетание образует единый научный термин, то дефис ставится (некоторые лингвисты считают, что в таких примерах приложений нет): заяц-русак, жук-плавунец, мышь-полёвка, жук-олень, птица-лира, рак-богомол, бабочка-капустница  (в таких случаях без родового понятия невозможно понять, о чём идёт речь: Мы поймали жука-оленя; Мы поймали оленя).

У нас не единый термин, значит, дефиса нет.